# How do I pass selection data to form using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have the below button which passes data to a modal. The issue I'm facing is how do I pass the info from 'data-selection' to the selection section in the form in the modal?

button

```html
 <form-group>
    <button 
    class="btn btn-primary md-trigger" 
    type="button"
    data-question="{{ $question->question}}" 
    data-section="{{ $question->sections->name}}"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#edit-question">Edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
 </form-group>
```

jquery:

```js
<script>
  $('#edit-question').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var modal = $(this)
    var question = button.data('question')
    var section = button.data('section')  
    modal.find('.modal-body #question').val(question);
    modal.find('.modal-body #section').val(section);
  })
</script>
```

form:

```html
<div class="form-group">
              <label>Section</label>
              <select class="custom-select form-control" name="section" id="section">
              <option selected>Choose Section</option>
              @foreach ($allSections as $section)
              <option value="{{ $section->id }}">{{ $section->name }}</option>
              @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: does `button.data('section')` gives you required value ? Also that value is there in your selection box ? because i tested this code its working fine .

Comment: Yes, I can get the data that section gives to output in the console. The problem I need to get around is how to replace "Choose Section", with the value from button.data('section')

Comment: this `modal.find('.modal-body #section').val(section);` works fines on my end .

Comment: That's odd because on the modal I get, the selection box is blank rather than showing the value from the button

Comment: You can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/4mvs7of9/3/) . Make sure your selection is under `modal-body` .